# Connect enterPressed() in QMainWindow to Button clicked()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt5

How can I connect a key enterPressed() event in my main GUI window to a specific button (also in main GUI)?

**Usecase:**

User starts the application, enter some data and press the Enter button and will be bypassed to a "Start" button is clicked.

My idea:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), ui.btn_Start, SLOT(clicked()));

class ClassA : QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    // ...

    private:
        Ui::ClassAClass ui;
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a `QMainWindow` for your use case?? `QDialog`s have [default buttons](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#default-button), and I think that `QDialog`s are better suited to a user entering some data and pressing Return. So, is there any reason for using `QMainWindow` here?

Comment: @Mike it is the Main window of the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect signals to other signals:

```
connect(this, &MainWindow::returnPressed, ui.btn_Start, &QPushButton::released);
```

And that is it. The signal is forwarded to `QPushButton`'s instance signal emitting it so whatever is connected to it will be invoked. Additionally (you talk about events) in `QMainWindow::keyPressEvent` you re-implement:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
//...
signals:
    void returnPressed() const;

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
};

void MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Return)
        emit returnPressed();
    QMainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: The problem is: QMainWindow has no member "returnPressed"

Comment: error: "The slot requires more arguments than the signal provides" and I think you have a typo: returnedPressed vs returnPressed

Comment: It works, thx. Typo keyPressEvent vs keyReleaseEvent and don't forget to change the connected Button signal from clicked to released!

Comment: @leon22 The keyReleaseEvent is not a typo but intention. You should generally use release instead of down/press/click. The reason is that the signal is emitted right after the thing happened (key is down) instead of when user completed the action (key was released, mouse button was released etc.). Especially with mouse clicks you may wish to cancel the action by dragging the clicked mouse away (from a button) but that is not possible if your signal is bound to "pressed" as it is then emitted immediately.

Comment: One additional question: I use a QMessageBox during the start of the tool to show Warnings/Errors ... and if the User press Enter to close the MessageBox it will also be catched by our keyReleaseEvent()! How can I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: @leon22 There are multiple options. The simplest one would be to make the connect only after you displayed the message box. Other option would be to temporarily block the signals during the message box. Another would be to use focus (only do it if MainWindow is focus widget qApp->focusWidget()). I would recommend the first one - deferring the connection after the initial  QMessageBox.